# Windows storage in windows 8 app

Tags: c#, windows-8

I use the following codes to save some contents into the IsolatedStorage for **windows phone apps**-

```
    public void SaveContent(string content)
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFile userStore =
        IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream =
        userStore.CreateFile(this.Filename))
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        {
            writer.Write(content);
        }
    }
```

Now i want to port the same to my **windows 8 app** but there are no similar codes in StorageFile for w8 i could find. Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `LocalFolder`.

```
var localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
```

For writing you have several choices. If you have an `IBuffer` then you can use `WriteBufferAsync`

```
var file = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
var buffer = GetBufferFromString("this is an example");
await FileIO.WriteBufferAsync(file, buffer);
```

The other option is to write using a stream.

```
var file = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
using (var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
{
   using(var outputStream = stream.GetOutputStreamAt(0))
   {
       var dataWriter = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataWriter(outputStream);
       dataWriter.WriteBytes(...);
       await dataWriter.StoreAsync();
       dataWriter.DetachStream();
       await outputStream.FlushAsync();
   }
}
```

You can read more here: [Quickstart: Reading and writing files (Windows Store apps using C#/VB/C++ and XAML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh758325.aspx).

Comment: When i try to run this code `sourcestream.WriteAsync(content);` , it throws an error and also i couldnt find `Write` while using sourcestream.

Answer (score 0):

You can read more about Storage [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700361.aspx).